Form onSubmit isn't triggered
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { z } from "zod";
import { api } from "@/trpc/react";
import { DatePickerWithRange } from "@/components/DatePickerWithRange";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormDescription,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { Country, State, City } from "country-state-city";
import type { ICity, ICountry, IState } from "country-state-city";

// Zod Schema for Form Validation
const tripFormSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, { message: "Name is required." }),
  destination: z.string().min(1, { message: "Destination is required." }),
  country: z.string().min(1, { message: "Country is required." }),
  state: z.string().min(1, { message: "State is required." }),
  city: z.string().min(1, { message: "City is required." }),
  hotelDetails: z.string().optional(),
  dateRange: z.object({
    from: z.date({
      required_error: "Start date is required.",
    }),
    to: z
      .date({
        required_error: "End date is required.",
      })
      .refine((val) => val > new Date(), {
        message: "End date must be after start date.",
      }),
  }),
  flightNumber: z.string().optional(),
});

export function CreateTripForm() {
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState<ICountry | null>(null);
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState<IState | null>(null);
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState<ICity | null>(null);

  const router = useRouter();

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof tripFormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(tripFormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      destination: "",
      country: "",
      state: "",
      city: "",
      hotelDetails: "",
      dateRange: {
        from: new Date(),
        to: new Date(),
      },
      flightNumber: "",
    },
  });

  const createTrip = api.post.create.useMutation({
    onSuccess: () => {
      router.refresh(); // Refresh the page or navigate if necessary
    },
    onError: (error: unknown) => {
      console.error("Error creating trip:", error);
    },
  });

  function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof tripFormSchema>) {
    console.log("Form submitted with data:", data); // Debugging statement

    const { dateRange, ...rest } = data;
    const updatedData = {
      ...rest,
      destination: selectedCity?.name ?? "",
      durationOfStay: Math.ceil(
        (dateRange.to.getTime() - dateRange.from.getTime()) /
          (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
      ),
    };
    console.log("Updated data:", updatedData); // Debugging statement
    createTrip.mutate(updatedData);
  }

  const handleCountryChange = (value: string) => {
    const country = Country.getAllCountries().find((c) => c.isoCode === value);
    setSelectedCountry(country ?? null);
    setSelectedState(null); // Reset state and city
    setSelectedCity(null);
    form.setValue("country", value); // Update form state
  };

  const handleStateChange = (value: string) => {
    const state = State.getStatesOfCountry(selectedCountry?.isoCode ?? "").find(
      (s) => s.isoCode === value,
    );
    setSelectedState(state ?? null);
    setSelectedCity(null); // Reset city
    form.setValue("state", value); // Update form state
  };

  const handleCityChange = (value: string) => {
    const city = City.getCitiesOfState(
      selectedState?.countryCode ?? "",
      selectedState?.isoCode ?? "",
    ).find((c) => c.name === value);
    setSelectedCity(city ?? null);
    form.setValue("city", value); // Update form state
  };

  const countries = Country.getAllCountries();
  const states = selectedCountry
    ? State.getStatesOfCountry(selectedCountry.isoCode)
    : [];
  const cities = selectedState
    ? City.getCitiesOfState(selectedState.countryCode, selectedState.isoCode)
    : [];

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className="my-10 flex w-full flex-col items-start justify-center gap-y-5 px-10"
      >
        <h1 className="mb-5 text-center text-2xl font-bold">Create a Trip</h1>

        {/* Name Field */}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="name"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  {...field}
                  placeholder="Enter trip name"
                  className="w-full"
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage>{form.formState.errors.name?.message}</FormMessage>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        {/* Country Selector */}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="country"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Country</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Select value={field.value} onValueChange={handleCountryChange}>
                  <SelectTrigger className="w-[280px]">
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a country" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectContent>
                    {countries.map((country) => (
                      <SelectItem key={country.isoCode} value={country.isoCode}>
                        {country.name}
                      </SelectItem>
                    ))}
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage>
                {form.formState.errors.country?.message}
              </FormMessage>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        {/* State Selector */}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="state"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>State</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Select
                  value={field.value}
                  onValueChange={handleStateChange}
                  disabled={!selectedCountry}
                >
                  <SelectTrigger className="w-[280px]">
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a state" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectContent>
                    {states.map((state) => (
                      <SelectItem key={state.isoCode} value={state.isoCode}>
                        {state.name}
                      </SelectItem>
                    ))}
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage>{form.formState.errors.state?.message}</FormMessage>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        {/* City Selector */}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="city"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>City</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Select
                  value={field.value}
                  onValueChange={handleCityChange}
                  disabled={!selectedState}
                >
                  <SelectTrigger className="w-[280px]">
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a city" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectContent>
                    {cities.map((city) => (
                      <SelectItem key={city.name} value={city.name}>
                        {city.name}
                      </SelectItem>
                    ))}
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage>{form.formState.errors.city?.message}</FormMessage>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        {/* Date Range Field */}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="dateRange"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
              <FormLabel>Date Range</FormLabel>
              <DatePickerWithRange
                className="w-[300px]"
                onChange={(dateRange) => field.onChange(dateRange)}
                value={field.value}
              />
              <FormDescription>
                Choose the date range for your trip.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        {/* Hotel Details Field */}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="hotelDetails"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Hotel Details</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  {...field}
                  placeholder="Enter hotel details"
                  className="w-full"
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage>
                {form.formState.errors.hotelDetails?.message}
              </FormMessage>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        {/* Flight Number Field */}
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="flightNumber"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Flight Number</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input
                  {...field}
                  placeholder="Enter flight number"
                  className="w-full"
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage>
                {form.formState.errors.flightNumber?.message}
              </FormMessage>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        {/* Submit Button */}
        <Button type="submit" className="mt-4">
          Create Trip
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default CreateTripForm;


I don't have anything in console not even a single error.
Please help me face this issue this is a code for hackathon and i need fast help.
I use shadcn form and my onsubmit doesn't get triggered i tried console.log while clicking on button and it worked and on form while submitting and it also worked but onSubmit never gets the form values

"Every form must be enclosed within a FORM element. There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested"
(see: The FORM element )

I think your problem might be coming from the tripFormSchema where you have all your states validations defined. The problem is specifically from the destination field. You have it required in your schema but there is no input or implementation that sets the value of this field in your code. Instead, you're calling it in your onSubmit function which gets triggered by the React Hook Form's handleSubmit function. The RHF handleSubmit function will not execute your form submission if all the required fields do not meet their set conditions. You might either want to write a. function that passes in value to the destination field before triggering form submission or just exempt it as a required field and you should be all good.
